# Rotate first page when printing

Tags: scribus

I have this two-sided layout that I need to print. The way my project is structured (a party flyer), the front page must be rotated 180° when printing, and the back page must stay as-is (or the other way around, it does not matter).

How can I rotate a page 180° in Scribus? Ideally I would just rotate when printing, but if there is no such option, I could rotate the page in the document after doing my editting.

I have found just the option of mirroring horizontally/vertically the pages, but I think that applies to all pages, not to a single one.

Comment: How are you printing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how to do that with scribus, but I have found out how to post-process the pdf. If `in.pdf` is the PDF exported with scribus:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
pdftk in.pdf cat 1S 2 output out.pdf
```

That command will take the first page and rotate it 180 degrees, and take the second page as-is.

Comment: Does this command line presume a 2 page document ("page 1 then page 2" or "page one, then everything after")?

Comment: I have only tested it with a 2 document page. If you have more pages, you need to copy the rest too, but I do not know the syntas for that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be:

1. On the first page, use "Advanced Select All" (Ctrl + Alt + A).
2. Under the "Page" menu, select "Manage page properties".
3. *Uncheck* "move objects with their page" and change the orientation to "Landscape".
4. Press F2 to open up the object properties.
5. Under "Geometry", set the basepoint to the center, and rotation to 180 degrees.

You may need to move the objects a little to line them up to the page after doing all of this.